# Finding Mean and Variance of a random variable

Tags: integration, statistics

$Y$ has distribution function:

$$F(y) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & y \le 0 \\
\frac{y}{8}, & 0<y<2 \\
\frac{y^2}{16}, & 2 \le y<4\\
1, & y \ge 4
\end{cases}$$

Find the mean and variance of $Y$.

$E(Y)=\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty} yf(y)$ $dy$

$=\int^0_{-\infty}y (0)$ $dy$+ $\frac{1}{8}\int ^2_0  y^2$ $dy$ $\frac{1}{16}\int^4_2 y^3 $ $dy$ +$\int^{\infty}_4 y$ $dy$

$=c+\frac{1}{3}+3.75-8+\infty$

I don't understand how to work on the $c$ and the $\infty$. Same logic shall be applied to find $E[Y^2]$ in order to find variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the CDF. This can be seen by the fact that it goes from $0$ to $1$ rather than having an area under it of $1$.

[image]

To get the PDF you need to differentiate your function:

$$f(y)=F'(y)=\begin{cases} 0,  & y < 0 \\ \frac{1}{8}, & 0<y<2 \\ \frac{y}{8}, & 2<y<4 \\ 0, & y>4 \end{cases}$$

You can then find $E(Y)$ using the formula you have:

$$E(Y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yf(y)\ dy$$

$$=\int_0^2\frac{y}{8}\ dy+\int_2^4\frac{y^2}{8}\ dy$$

$$=\left[\frac{y^2}{16}\right]_0^2+\left[\frac{y^3}{24}\right]_2^4$$

$$=\frac{4}{16}-\frac{0}{16}+\frac{64}{24}-\frac{8}{24}$$

$$=\frac{31}{12}$$

For finding variance you could do $VAR(Y)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$ or alternatively as we've found $E(X)$ you can do $VAR(Y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty(y-\mu)^2f(y)dy$

$$E(Y^2)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2f(y)dy$$

$$=\int_0^2 \frac{y^2}{8}\ dy+\int_2^4\frac{y^3}{8}\ dy$$

$$=\left[\frac{y^3}{24}\right]_0^2+\left[\frac{y^4}{32}\right]_2^4$$

$$=\frac{8}{24}-\frac{0}{24}+\frac{256}{32}-\frac{16}{32}$$

$$=\frac{47}{6}$$

Hence:

$$VAR(Y)=\frac{47}{6}-\left(\frac{31}{12}\right)^2=\frac{167}{144}$$

Answer (score 2):

The expected value comes from integrating the pdf, while you are given the cdf. So you must first differentiate $F$ to find your pdf.
So you will actually be integrating the function

$f(y) =$ 
\begin{cases}
0,  & y < 0 \\
\frac{1}{8}, & 0<y<2 \\
\frac{y}{8}, & 2 < y<4\\
0, & y > 4
\end{cases}